# Как получить доступ к элементу в React JS

Tags: reactjs

Доброго всем времени суток.

Как получить доступ к элементу в одном методе-обработчике?

```
class FirstContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    getCLk(){

        console.log(this.refs.txt);
    }

    render(){        
        return (
            <ul>
                <li onClick={this.getCLk.bind(this)} ref="txt" key={0}>FIRST</li>
                <li onClick={this.getCLk.bind(this)} ref="txt" key={1}>SECOND</li>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

Хотелось бы, чтобы выбирался элемент по которому кликают. Сейчас выбирается последний. Можно ли это описать в одном методе и не ставить различные ref?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: можно немного подробнее, что вы хотите сделать?

Answer (score 3):

```
getCLk(e){
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Рефы в данном случае не нужны